# Why is wpf helpers needed for Reactive extensions

Tags: wpf, winforms

Why did the developers of `Reactive extensions` need to implement a different library for WPF? In what way was WinForms insufficient so that such a library was implemented?

Comment: I know nothing about Rx, but winforms is insufficient in every possible way I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

The WPF Helpers package for Rx is specifically a set of wrappers that port the WPF `Dispatcher` into the `IScheduler` theme used throughout Rx. They are **NOT** required for non-WPF applications.

Answer (score 0):

Because the underlying threading models are different between the platforms (WinForm vs WPF vs WinRT...) the team moved to a provider model enabled through the core platform services. The team wrote extensively behind their decision to make this change on their blog. See for example -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/08/15/reactive-extensions-v2-0-has-arrived.aspx.